# Adding cells based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula in excel that:

1) Goes through a column (A:A)

2) Finds a specific word (i.e dog)

3) If the word found is equal to the word specified, then take the value in Column B and add it to the other rows where the same condition is true.

In the example below if `dog` is specified, then all the cells in column B that have the word `dog` in the column A cell next to it will be added (The answer will therefore be 9)

```
(A) (B)
dog  1
dog  3
cat  4
lion 5
cat  3
cat  2
dog  5
lion 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"dog",B:B)
```

**EDIT:** To look for `dog` after the first 4 characters you can use:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"????dog",B:B)
```

(if you want to skip only 3 characters as the `MID("AZ Dog",4,3)` suggests, delete one `?`)

If you want to find cell ending with `dog` use:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*dog",B:B)
```

Starting with `dog`:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"dog*",B:B)
```

Including `dog` anywhere:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*dog*",B:B)
```

Comment: I need to something a little more complicated now. I need to do the same thing but instead of just looking for dog I need to use the MID function to find the 3 characters after the first 4 `MID("AZ Dog",4,3)` in column A and if they are equal to dog sum the corresponding ones in column B.